# Message queue with time to live

Tags: java, collections, message-queue, java.util.concurrent

I look for a queue that stores up to `N` elements for a certain time (i.e. 10 sec) or should dispose the oldest value if full.

I found a similar queue in the Apache Collections (`CircularFifoQueue` [JavaDoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/index.html)) that misses the aspect of time to live. A full fletched message broker seems like an overhead for my small project.

Do you mind giving me a hint how I should implement this? Shall I filter out old values while I poll for elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to following queue implementation. The code is heavily based on Apaches [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html) and is only weakly tested. Moreover the implementation is **not thread-safe** and **not serializable**.

Leave a comment if you spot a mistake.

```
import java.util.AbstractCollection;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * TimedQueue is a first-in first-out queue with a fixed size that
 * replaces its oldest element if full.
 * <p>
 * The removal order of a {@link TimedQueue} is based on the
 * insertion order; elements are removed in the same order in which they
 * were added.  The iteration order is the same as the removal order.
 * <p>
 * The {@link #add(Object)}, {@link #remove()}, {@link #peek()}, {@link #poll},
 * {@link #offer(Object)} operations all perform in constant time.
 * All other operations perform in linear time or worse.
 * <p>
 * This queue prevents null objects from being added and it is not thread-safe and not serializable.
 * 
 * The majority of this source code was copied from Apaches {@link CircularFifoQueue}: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html
 *
 * @version 1.0
 */
public class TimedQueue<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
implements Queue<E> {

/** Underlying storage array. */
private Item<E>[] elements;

/** Array index of first (oldest) queue element. */
private int start = 0;

/**
 * Index mod maxElements of the array position following the last queue
 * element.  Queue elements start at elements[start] and "wrap around"
 * elements[maxElements-1], ending at elements[decrement(end)].
 * For example, elements = {c,a,b}, start=1, end=1 corresponds to
 * the queue [a,b,c].
 */
private transient int end = 0;

/** Flag to indicate if the queue is currently full. */
private transient boolean full = false;

/** Capacity of the queue. */
private final int maxElements;

private TimeUnit unit;
private int delay;

/**
 * Constructor that creates a queue with the default size of 32.
 */
public TimedQueue() {
    this(32);
}

/**
 * Constructor that creates a queue with the specified size.
 *
 * @param size  the size of the queue (cannot be changed)
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException  if the size is &lt; 1
 */
public TimedQueue(final int size) {
    this(size, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public TimedQueue(final int size, int delay, TimeUnit unit) {
    if (size <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The size must be greater than 0");
    }
    elements = new Item[size];
    maxElements = elements.length;
    this.unit = unit;
    this.delay = delay;
}

/**
 * Constructor that creates a queue from the specified collection.
 * The collection size also sets the queue size.
 *
 * @param coll  the collection to copy into the queue, may not be null
 * @throws NullPointerException if the collection is null
 */
public TimedQueue(final Collection<? extends E> coll) {
    this(coll.size());
    addAll(coll);
}

/**
 * Returns the number of elements stored in the queue.
 *
 * @return this queue's size
 */
@Override
public int size() {
    int size = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(validElement(i) != null) {
            size++;
        }
    }

    return size;
}

/**
 * Returns true if this queue is empty; false otherwise.
 *
 * @return true if this queue is empty
 */
@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

private boolean isAtFullCapacity() {
    return size() == maxElements;
}

/**
 * Clears this queue.
 */
@Override
public void clear() {
    full = false;
    start = 0;
    end = 0;
    Arrays.fill(elements, null);
}

/**
 * Adds the given element to this queue. If the queue is full, the least recently added
 * element is discarded so that a new element can be inserted.
 *
 * @param element  the element to add
 * @return true, always
 * @throws NullPointerException  if the given element is null
 */
@Override
public boolean add(final E element) {
    if (null == element) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Attempted to add null object to queue");
    }

    if (isAtFullCapacity()) {
        remove();
    }

    elements[end++] = new Item<E>(element);

    if (end >= maxElements) {
        end = 0;
    }

    if (end == start) {
        full = true;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Returns the element at the specified position in this queue.
 *
 * @param index the position of the element in the queue
 * @return the element at position {@code index}
 * @throws NoSuchElementException if the requested position is outside the range [0, size)
 */
public E get(final int index) {
    final int sz = size();
    if (sz == 0) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException(
                String.format("The specified index (%1$d) is outside the available range because the queue is empty.", Integer.valueOf(index)));
    }
    if (index < 0 || index >= sz) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException(
                String.format("The specified index (%1$d) is outside the available range [0, %2$d]",
                              Integer.valueOf(index), Integer.valueOf(sz-1)));
    }

    final int idx = (start + index) % maxElements;
    return validElement(idx);
}

private E validElement(int idx) {
    if(elements[idx] == null){
        return null;
    }
    long diff = System.currentTimeMillis() - elements[idx].getCreationTime();

    if(diff < unit.toMillis(delay)) {
        return (E) elements[idx].getValue();
    } else {
        elements[idx] = null;
        return null;
    }
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Adds the given element to this queue. If the queue is full, the least recently added
 * element is discarded so that a new element can be inserted.
 *
 * @param element  the element to add
 * @return true, always
 * @throws NullPointerException  if the given element is null
 */
public boolean offer(E element) {
    return add(element);
}

public E poll() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return remove();
}

public E element() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("queue is empty");
    }
    return peek();
}

public E peek() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return (E) elements[start].getValue();
}

public E remove() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("queue is empty");
    }

    final E element = validElement(start);
    if (null != element) {
        elements[start++] = null;

        if (start >= maxElements) {
            start = 0;
        }
        full = false;
    }
    return element;
}

/**
 * Increments the internal index.
 *
 * @param index  the index to increment
 * @return the updated index
 */
private int increment(int index) {
    index++;
    if (index >= maxElements) {
        index = 0;
    }
    return index;
}

/**
 * Decrements the internal index.
 *
 * @param index  the index to decrement
 * @return the updated index
 */
private int decrement(int index) {
    index--;
    if (index < 0) {
        index = maxElements - 1;
    }
    return index;
}

/**
 * Returns an iterator over this queue's elements.
 *
 * @return an iterator over this queue's elements
 */
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<E>() {

        private int index = start;
        private int lastReturnedIndex = -1;
        private boolean isFirst = full;

        public boolean hasNext() {
            return (isFirst || index != end) && size() > 0;
        }

        public E next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            isFirst = false;
            lastReturnedIndex = index;
            index = increment(index);
            if(validElement(lastReturnedIndex) == null) {
                return next();
            } else {
                return validElement(lastReturnedIndex);
            }
        }

        public void remove() {
            if (lastReturnedIndex == -1) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }

            // First element can be removed quickly
            if (lastReturnedIndex == start) {
                TimedQueue.this.remove();
                lastReturnedIndex = -1;
                return;
            }

            int pos = lastReturnedIndex + 1;
            if (start < lastReturnedIndex && pos < end) {
                // shift in one part
                System.arraycopy(elements, pos, elements, lastReturnedIndex, end - pos);
            } else {
                // Other elements require us to shift the subsequent elements
                while (pos != end) {
                    if (pos >= maxElements) {
                        elements[pos - 1] = elements[0];
                        pos = 0;
                    } else {
                        elements[decrement(pos)] = elements[pos];
                        pos = increment(pos);
                    }
                }
            }

            lastReturnedIndex = -1;
            end = decrement(end);
            elements[end] = null;
            full = false;
            index = decrement(index);
        }

    };
}

private static final class Item<E> {
    private long creationTime;
    private E in;

    public Item(E in) {
        this.in = in;
        creationTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public E getValue() {
        return in;
    }

    public long getCreationTime() {
        return creationTime;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a class called [LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which has a special method for removing stale data.  From the documentation:

> protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest)
>   Returns true if this map should remove its eldest entry.

The method `removeEldestEntry` is called whenever anything is added to the list (queue).  If it returns `true` then the eldest entry is removed to make room for the new entry, otherwise nothing is removed.  You can add your own implementation which checks the timestamp on the eldest entry and returns `true` if it be older than a threshhold for expiration (e.g. 10 seconds).  So your implementation might look something like this:

```
protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
    long currTimeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long entryTimeMillis = eldest.getValue().getTimeCreation();

    return (currTimeMillis - entryTimeMillis) > (1000*10*60); 
}
```

Comment: I will check on that and keep you posted!

Comment: This answer is great!

Comment: The method `removeEldestEntry` is only called, if a new entry is added. old values remain in the Map.

Comment: @Markus Is this a problem for you?  Old values will all eventually be removed.  I believe my answer will fit your needs well.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I planed to have a message queue because the data will be transferred over the wire (bottleneck). Every reduction is more than welcome.

Comment: Just limit the size of the queue if you want, and use my solution to kick out any stale entries if new ones come in.  I believe you can make the current interface work for your use case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: I gave an answer on my own question. Do you mind when I do not accept your answer? I will like your comments in order to reward your efforts.

Comment: @Markus I support whatever lets you solve your problem.  Let me know if I can be of further assistance.

Answer (score 2):

I think [java.util.LinkedHashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html#removeEldestEntry(java.util.Map.Entry)) is the solution for you. It has a `removeEldest()` method which is called whenever an entry is put in the map. You can override it to indicate if the eldest entry should be removed.

The JavaDoc gives a good example:

```
 private static final int MAX_ENTRIES = 100;

 protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
    return size() > MAX_ENTRIES;
 }
```

This removes the eldest entry if the map has more than 100 entries.

Pro-actively removing items after 10 seconds would require a separate thread to check age and remove old items. I am guessing this is not what you want, judging by your description.

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Comment: This looks like a good idea. However, I want to remove items older than a 10 seconds. Is there already an implementation of such a "time based queue"?